# In Python why does a tuple of integers take up less space than distinct integers?

Tags: python, sizeof, tuples

Here's an example with random integers:

```
a, b, c, d = 79412623, 56529819571, 10431, 30461
t = (79412623, 56529819571, 10431, 30461)
```

And their sizes:

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(t) # 88
aa, bb, cc, dd = sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b), sys.getsizeof(c), sys.getsizeof(d)
sum([aa,bb,cc,dd]) # 96
```

Why does the tuple take up less space?

Comment: Might want to `sum(map(sys.getsizeof, (a,b,c,d)))` next time. Repetitive text gets clumsy for many reasons, for instance here the line was too wide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number returned by `sys.getsizeof` doesn't include the size of the objects contained by a container.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof({1:2})
280
>>> sys.getsizeof({'a_really_long_string_that_takes_up_lots_of_space':'foo'})
280
```

Comment: To expand on this, that's because the containers simply contain references. Python doesn't pass objects themselves around, and has no concept of "primitive types" like Java; but some modules do store values instead of object references, like array and numpy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a 32-bit Windows XP, with Python 2.6.2, and I tried your code, which looks like this:

In [15]: a,b,c,d=79412623, 56529819571, 10431, 30461

In [16]: t=(79412623, 56529819571, 10431, 30461)

In [17]: sys.getsizeof(t)
Out[17]: 44

In [18]: aa, bb, cc, dd = sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b), sys.getsizeof(c), sys.getsizeof(d)

In [19]: sum([aa,bb,cc,dd])
Out[19]: 56